# What this means,f(x)=y in case of surjective function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$x$ means input, $y$ means output so $$f(x)=y$$ means any input that goes into this function give the $y$ that means output, but how this can prove a function is surjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only meaningful to talk about a function being *surjective* (or not) if you specify the sets involved: for a function $f$ from a set $X$ to a set $Y$, a function is called **surjective** if for every $y \in Y$, there exists at least one $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. In other words: for a function to be called *surjective*, all elements of $Y$ have to be the image of some $x \in X$.

Let me clarify this with an example; consider the functions:
$$f: \color{green}{\mathbb{R}} \to \color{red}{\mathbb{R}} : y = x^2$$
and
$$g: \color{green}{\mathbb{R}} \to \color{blue}{\mathbb{R^+}} : y = x^2$$

Notice that $f$ is not surjective because you can take $-1 \in \color{red}{\mathbb{R}}$ but there is no $x \in \color{green}{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $f(x) = -1$ since $f(x) = x^2 \ge 0$ for all $x$.

On the other hand, you can take any $y \in \color{blue}{\mathbb{R^+}}$ and there will always be an $x \in \color{green}{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $f(x) = y$ (take $x = \sqrt{y}$); so $g$ is *surjective*.

The explicit formula "$y=f(x)$" is the same for $f$ and $g$, but one is surjective while the other isn't.

Comment: I don't understand how this f(x)=y tells that all elements of Y have to be the image of some x∈X,how this statement tell this?

Comment: The formula "$y=f(x)$" doesn't tell you that. What I wrote about *"for all elements of $Y$, there has to be..."* is the **definition** of a surjection. You don't choose this; you should check your book / course notes to see if you can find this definition.

Comment: **such that f(x)=y** -what this means?

Comment: That you have to be able to find an $x$-value, such that the image $f(x)$ is equal to the $y$ you picked from the set $Y$.

Comment: ** That you have to be able to find an x-value, such that the image f(x) is equal to the y you picked from the set  Y.** what this means please describe this.It was my real question.