# Unresolved questions about surjective function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> f is surjective if and only if  f(x) = y

1.How the above formula applied on any surjective function prove this: every element of the range corresponds to at least one member of the domain

2.What should be proved f(x)=y or y=f(x)?

3.Are the results of these two situations same and how?

4.f(x)=y means that,for all x there is some y(that is the primary condition of a relation to be a function).Shouldn't we prove that y=f(x), for all y there is some x(which is the main condition of surjective function)

5.I a function f(x)=x to the power of 2, if my domain is {1,2,3},codomain is {1,4,9,16}.for f(x)=y it is surjective but for y=f(x) it is not,isn't it?

Finally what they are telling f(x)=y and y=f(x)?

Comment: The definition you cite is nonsense, so the answers to all your questions are "because that's not the definition of a surjective function." (Also, previously asked: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952276/what-this-means-fx-y-in-case-of-surjective-function)

Comment: Equivalence is a symmetric relation!

Comment: Why is this being aggressively down voted? It's an honest question.

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a lot going on in your question, so I'll try my best to hit all the relevant parts.

A function is a relation between two sets, the domain and the codomain. In formal settings, when you define a function you must give its domain and codomain as part of the definition. However, often times this is left out and the sets are assumed from context. For example, in pre-calculus, you often see questions like "what is the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$?" which is often meant to be understood as "what is the largest subset of the real numbers you can take to be the domain?"

Now, your question is about surjectivity (also called onto). The correct definition is: a function is surjective if every element in the codomain has a pre-image in the domain, i.e. to fix what you wrote "f is surjective if and only if for every $y$ in the codomain, there exists an $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$". Using the terminology of range, we could also define it as when the range is the whole codomain.

Some of your other questions aren't very clear and I'd recommend you ask them separately if you still have confusions.

For your last question, if we define $f(x)=x^2$ with domain $\{1,2,3\}$ and codomain $\{1,4,9,16\}$ then it is no surjective as the range is just $\{f(1)=1, f(2)=4,f(3)=9\}$ and thus does not include $16$. However, if we remove 16 from the codomain or change the domain to include 4, then it is surjective.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, but does not address what appears to be the deep confusion of the OP: `for f(x)=y it is surjective but for y=f(x) it is not`. That confusion stems from the misunderstanding (and misquoting on the first line) of what the definition of surjectivity is.

Comment: @dxiv I edited it a bit, let me know if you think this still misses the confusion. Based on the OP's question history, I'm not sure what kind of help to give, to be honest. Perhaps a diagram...